# Should we use constants with builder methods in Java?

Tags: java

Say, I am creating an object using the builder pattern as follows:

```
CfnResolverProps props = CfnResolverProps.builder()
.apiId(“TestApiId”)
.typeName("Query")
.fieldName(“list”)
.dataSourceName(“SomeName”)
.build()
```

So, here, is it a good idea to make static constants variables for all the TestApiId, Query, list, SomeName? Or with builder pattern, it does not matter? For me, here, it doesn’t matter much because, here it is already readable code as builderPattern tells the name of the fields explicitly. What are the guidelines people use to use constants in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind using constant is that it's immutable and not going to change.

To address your question, do you think the string literals that are used in the construction of object `CfnResolverProps` are going to be used else where as well?

If the answer is yes, you should create constants for those literals. If the answer is no, it's okay to keep the code as-is.